# How to change labels on the control button in NVD3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

Here is my problem: on the NVD3 charts, there are sometimes options like "Stacked" or "Grouped" with radio buttons.

What I would like to do is to change the label of these buttons. As I'm french, I would like to have "Groupé" in place of "Grouped" and "Empilé" in place of "Stacked". Don't know if I'm clear?

Is it possible? I already took a look in the different js files like "legend", tooltips"... but it wasn't really helpful (for the javascript and nvd3 newbie I am...).

Thank's for your answers!

Answer (score 3):

The strings for those labels are unfortunately hardcoded in the source (in the respective file in `models/`), so you would have to change the source. The generated control elements with the text have no specific ID or class such that selecting and changing them dynamically is not really an option.

Your best bet is to change the source. Just search the Javascript files for the strings you want to change.

Comment: Thank's for the answer! I started to look in the source before asking the question and had understood that I would have to change the source but I can't find the damn line :/

Comment: I find "Stacked" in the following files in `models/`: `stackedAreaChart.js`, `multiBarChart.js`, `multiBarTimeSeriesChart.js`, `multiBarHorizontalChart.js`.

Comment: Indeed, I found it too but it dosen't change anything when I replace "Stacked" and "Grouped" with something else

Comment: You might have to restart your browser to prevent it from caching the files.

Comment: Found it! It works now! It was the line we are talking about but I just didn't updated the javascript file on my webserver :/ Thank's Lars!

Answer (score 2):

Just to bring this answer up to date: in version 1.8 you can do:

```
chart = nv.models.multiBarChart()
    .controlLabels({"grouped":"Groupé","stacked":"Empilé"})
    // add your other chart parameters, eg color, margin etc here
;
```